# Hue Light Strip - Best outdoor, long run equivalent?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, weather-resistant

Purpose is to light up a path along a dark area in the woods behind the house .

Requirements

- Able to run 200 ft, at a price less than Hue Strips which are quite expensive.
- Either weather proof, or coverable by some sort of partially transparent diffusing conduit.
- Dimmable.  So it can be a subtle peaceful effect that doesn’t light up Christmas tree bright

Notes / Questions

- Not sure if these are good power options: I’ve considered micro trenching a 110v power
  cable, or using solar with battery.  I see things on Amazon using 12v a lot but not sure why.
- Don’t want to put those torchlights you buy at Home Depot and mount every 10 feet. It’s just personal preference, don’t like that look, and hopefully the LED strip can look like a continuous band of light with some basic diffusing.
- RGB colors would be a cool, but not absolutely necessary for a walking path
- Home automation standards are not necessary.  It would be nice, but I’d be happy with any standalone app that let me control the lights from Inside.
- Actually haven’t heard of dimmable light strings before outside of the Hue, but I see quite a few different options especially 12 V be used on Amazon, but I’m not sure how they would fit into a solution.
- Already have good wifi coverage

Any feedback or ideas appreciated.

Comment: any 12v strip can be easily dimmed. you can get cheap+decent led strip on amazon, for about $2/meter. 200' is too far for one power supply. At a decent "brightness", you'll need about  0.33A/meter for 30 LEDs/m strips. Since you need about 60 Meters, that's 20A, which requires some expensive wiring. I would run 110v to the opposite end and use 2 10A power supplies, or maybe 4 5A supplies, tapping off the AC as needed. You can drop the current some and get by with less, but you're main problem is pure length.

Answer (score 1):

Search on Wish or AliExpress for “solar light string” - these things cost almost nothing and look nice and do provide light. Usually they have some kind of settings like different patterns or intensities.

For wired: There are other “LED strips” that you have to do more work to wire up, but the possibilities are endless - RGB, or variations of warm or cool white, or other colors. Most come with remotes, so you can make adjustments. There are specific strips that are waterproof (encased in rubber).  They all run on 12v so you can use transformers and plug into 110, or do things like use a solar panel.